# How to move App.xaml and not to break designer?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have WPF project and some resources defined in App.xaml that are used in other files. When I try to move App.xaml to subdirectory designer is no longer able to find those resources. My project still compiles since I use 'Startup' event instead of 'StartupUri'. How to tell the designer where to search for resources? How it knows where they are when App.xaml is in root of project?

**Update:**
Project files:

App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Startup="startup">
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" x:Key="brush" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class App : System.Windows.Application
    {
        private void startup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            new MainWindow().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="300" Width="300" Background="{StaticResource brush}" />
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**
Uploaded zipped solution to http://zalil.ru/30771604 (download will start automatically)

Mirror: http://www.speedyshare.com/files/27697250/WpfApplication1.zip

Comment: I see what I did differently. Thanks for the source. I'll tinker a bit more.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes. Windows 7 x64 SP1, VS 2010, Target framework v3.5 SP1

Comment: Well I meant VS2010 SP1. I installed it and it didn't resolve your problem. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't duplicate the problem on my end.  Here's what I tried:

I created a application with a style in the resources of App.xaml. I moved App.xaml to a subdirectory. I have another window that uses the style defined in the resources of App.xaml (he resides in a different directory) and it was able to resolve it just fine. I added ..\ to the beginning of my original `StartupUri`.

I did some searching, what version of Visual Studio are you using? Apparently there may be an bug related to your problem in VS2008:

http://bengribaudo.com/blog/2010/08/19/106/bug-single-application-resources-entry-ignored

He says a workaround for this bug is to set the `x:Name` attribute on `Application`.  Hope that helps!

EDIT: I also tried handling the `Startup` event instead of using the `StartupUri` and it still worked fine.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
     private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
     {
          new MainWindow().Show();
     }
}
```

EDIT PART 2:

Okay, I enclosed the SolidColorBrush inside a ResourceDictionary as such:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" x:Key="brush" /> 
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the window picks up the brush. The designer doesn't like it, but when I change from StaticResource to DynamicResource it stops complaining.

EDIT 3:

I just thought of something. Do you have VS2010 SP1 installed? It fixed [some bugs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2010/12/20/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1-beta-feedback.aspx) with the designer.

And sorry, my edit number 2 didn't work as expected. I noticed my blue squiggles were gone in the xaml, but I didn't check the designer. x__x

Comment: Weird. I'm using VS 2010 and you did exactly what I tried. Wait a moment, I'll upload test project.

Comment: Uploaded solution archive. Check it out please.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work for me. Added ResourceDictionary and changed StaticResource to DynamicResource. Program still runs successfully but designer cant resolve resource. Are you sure you didn't change something else?

Answer (score 3):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKwQ4.png). Move you App.xaml to your desired location

[image: App.xaml Moved]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja7an.png). Refactor you App.xaml.cs namespace to accommodate the new change:

[image: Refactor its namespace]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnFyo.png). Rebuild your solution.

[4]. Go to your project properies and set the Startup object to your App.xaml file at the new location.

[image: set the Startup object to your App.xaml]

[5]. Run your application and it should work successfully :)

Comment: Same situation here. Project builds, but designer doesn't work.