# WPF Why does design view fail if I move my window and app into a subfolder of visual studio

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MaroonGradientBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
  <GradientStop Color="#FF0C0B0B" Offset="1"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#FFBF5656"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

```
<Window 
  x:Class="GraphViewerWindow"
  RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Unspecified"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:DaedalusGraphViewer="clr-namespace:DaedalusGraphViewer"
  Title="Window1" Height="900" Width="900">
  <TextBox Background="{StaticResource MaroonGradientBrush}" />
</Window>
```

the program opens up with a window with the correct gradient brush. However, the design view still doesn't load the window because it can't find maroongradientbrush.

Edit:

Found my problem. It is this exactly:

[How to move App.xaml and not to break designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492090/how-to-move-app-xaml-and-not-to-break-designer)

but there isn't a posted solution to it

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML is wrong. That's why it's not working

Put back these into App.xaml in the following manner:

```
<Application ...>
   <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GraphViewerBrushes.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GraphViewerTreeViewResources.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/SignalScrollViewerResources.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/ValidationErrorResources.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/GraphViewerToolbarResources.xaml" />
               <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionaries/SavedResourcesIMightUse.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       </ResourceDictionary>
   </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

If you put all these resources into EACH UserControl of your app, you will create a horrendous memory hog.

`StaticResource`s should work just fine. I do it this way in my projects and never had any problems. even if your resources are stored in external assemblies (`pack://applicaton`, etc)